# Scale and move a text smoothly with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, smoothing

I'm having a text scaled and moved via JavaScript / jQuery. I can't use jQuerys animate() because it has to fade in and out and has to be repeated and with more elements (end result: "flying" from the background, moving in different directions and fading out).

My problem: It's not running smoothly and causes quite the cpu-usage. Here's a stripped down version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">

    var steps = 300; // steps from start to finish

    // the final css values
    var endValueTop = 300;
    var endValueLeft = 300;
    var endValueFontSize = 100;

    // the current css values (get encreased in doAnimation())
    var currentValueTop = 100;
    var currentValueLeft = 100;
    var currentValueFontSize = 0;

    // the added values in each step
    var stepsTop = (endValueTop - currentValueTop) / steps;
    var stepsLeft = (endValueLeft - currentValueLeft) / steps;
    var stepsFontSize = (endValueFontSize - currentValueFontSize) / steps;

    function doAnimation() {

        // increase current values
        currentValueTop += stepsTop;
        currentValueLeft += stepsLeft;
        currentValueFontSize += stepsFontSize;

        // apply them
        $("#hello").css({
            top: currentValueTop,
            left: currentValueLeft,
            fontSize: currentValueFontSize
        });

        // restart if there are steps left
        if (steps--) {
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                doAnimation();
            }, 50);

        }

    }

    // start the first time
    doAnimation();

</script>

<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
  body { position: relative; }
  p#hello { position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px; font-size: 0px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Running example on [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/oxode).

Any suggestions? Bonus: How to reduce the cpu load? Thanks a lot!

Steffen

Comment: what's wrong with using `.animate()`? Here's a demo using it - http://jsbin.com/oxode/2 You should be able to fade in and out without problem using `animate` too

Comment: @Russ Cam: Increasing and decreasing opacity in one run (and other things) don't let me. I wish I could though…

Comment: How about if it was split up into several calls to `animate` that made the text grow continuously and its position on the page shift down and right, but also allowed you to make the calls to change opacity to fade in and out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first off, absolutely do not use jQuery within a 50ms timer. If anything is causing high CPU usage it is that. Use something like this instead

```
var hello = $('#hello')[0].style;

function doAnimation() {

  //code...

  hello.top = curentValueTop + 'px';
  hello.left = currentValueLeft + 'px';
  hello.fontSize = currentValueFontSize + 'px';

  //rest of code...

}
```

However, smoothly and consistently scaling of fonts is something most browsers do not handle well. Since 99% of the time the text on a web page is not flying into your face, we do not notice this. You might have more luck with an image of the text rendered at the maximum font size you need.

Also, 50ms ~= 20fps which is not a particularly smooth frame rate for animations that traverse half of the screen. If not using jQuery significantly reduces CPU usage you could try a smaller interval. Of course most browsers are not good at handling high frame rate animations either.

Yup, modern web browsers, struggling to do things that 20 year old video game consoles had no problem with, at a quarter of the frame rate.

**EDIT** Try this http://jsbin.com/oxode/4/edit

I used the `em` unit for `fontSize` as it accepts fractional numbers, and used a 15ms timer (about 60fps if the browser can keep up). As you can see it scales smoother, although you will have to adjust your animation settings a bit...

Comment: I can see that this should performe much better (couldn't see the effect though, probably not testing correctly). Thanks, I learned something. But doesn't solve the text-jumping.

Comment: also in the `setTimeout` call, look at using either `window.setTimeout(doAnimation, 15);` or `window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, 15);` to remove the unneccessary anonymous function wrapping the function call

Comment: @Steffen Wenzel the text jumping depends a lot on the browser. It seemed smoothest to me in Firefox. Also consider using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` (http://jsbin.com/oxode/5/edit) might result in a smoother animation. But in the end you are probably going to get some text jumping no matter what, which is why I suggested using an image instead if that is practical.

Comment: Switching to EM really makes a big difference, especially in Safari (Firefox seems to be able to deal with pixel fractions). Images are not practical but would do the trick, I agree. I will also try the setInterval.
The main problem with my code was px instead of em, so your answer pretty much solves my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've coded an animation in javascript + html5: There were over 30 images that needed to be moved, stretched and rendered each frame. I could easily put the framerate up to 200fps without optimising anything. I think your answer is perfect as he's needing only one image and without jQuery there's be plenty of cpu time to get a smooth viewing experience

Answer (score 0):

I've used this library some years ago quite successfully on cellphones, maybe it has little enough overhead to make it fast enough for you:

http://dev.opera.com/libraries/animation/

Comment: Should have the same drawbacks as jQuerys animate().

Answer (score 0):

jQuery wasn't really designed for long animations (that's why "slow" is less than 1 second) so high CPU load isn't really going to go away.

One thing you could do is to use the animate function
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

That already does a lot of what you had programmed there.

Comment: Yeah, that would have brought down this code to three lines. But I also have to deal with increasing AND decreasing opacity in one animation. And using one interval for the five or so elements I'm moving parallel seems faster to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>

<style>
#txt{position:absolute; left:0px;}
</style>

<div id="txt">Salam</div>   <br><br>
<button onclick="setTimeout(fn, 200)">GO ON</button>

<script>
function fn() {document.getElementById("txt").style.left="200px";
               document.getElementById("txt").style.transition="2s";
              }
</script></body></html>
```

Native JS and CSS can handle this.
In the CSS, set your default text position.
In JavaScript, 2 steps:
1 = Set the new position.
2 = Add "transition" value to you style attibute.